# What am I changing by adding i-- or i++ to my while loop?

Tags: c#, loops, math, while-loop

I am trying to get a handle on how to increment and decrement math problems with loops, and I've been messing with multiplication and division but can't quite get it right.  My current confusion is why the math does't work out to what I am attempting to do. I am assuming it is my lack of understanding of C# syntax regarding loops.

```
        int i = 6;

        while(i-- > 0)
        { Console.WriteLine(i / 2); }
```

I would expect to divide 6 continuously until it gets to 1. 
However the output is something like 2,2,1,1,0,0. This is the correct number of integers, but I'm really confused as to what it's outputting. If I change it from that to this:

```
        int i = 6;

        while(i++ > 24)
        { Console.WriteLine(i * 2); }
```

It doesn't multiply 6 by 2 until it reaches 24, instead it multiples 14 by 2 until it hits 48. Is there a way I can change this so that it does what I expect it to?

Answer (score 1):

The first question is about integer division.  An integer divided by an integer will always be an integer, so any remainder is dropped.  Thus:

```
5 / 2 = 2
4 / 2 = 2
3 / 2 = 1
2 / 2 = 1
1 / 2 = 0
0 / 2 = 0
```

The second question doesn't really make sense to me, because I wouldn't expect the loop to be entered at all.  You just declared `i = 6`, and since `i++ > 24` is false then the loop should never be entered at all.  I suspect you're mis-debugged something somewhere.

---

As a side note, I wouldn't recommend structuring your code like that.  Things like `while (i-- > 0)` can be misleading or confusing when reading code, requiring the person reading it to have to stop and think about it for a bit or perhaps debug it.

Keep your comparisons and your operations separate.  The same loop can be done like this:

```
while (i > 0)
{
    i--;
    Console.WriteLine(i / 2);
}
```

Comment: Oops, you're right about the second one, the > should be a <.

Comment: @Patrick: In which case I would expect it to start at 14, since 7 * 2 is 14.

Comment: Thank you, I think I am somewhat getting what is going on!